# Windows shared drive permissions when mounted on Mac as SMB

Tags: macos, smb

I am sharing a drive on windows xp (64-bit) over the network and it is set such that the group 'Everyone' has read and modify permissions. (no full control).
From the mac, when I connect to server as smb://fileshare, the folder that is mounted has contents under it that have restricted permissions.
Only the mac user seems to have read-write permissions, no access permissions for others.

What is the best way to make all files in this share carry over the same permissions as on the Windows host? Is this something related to inheritance, since I think no inheritance has been enabled on the Windows side.
Running a chmod on mac recursively on this mounted share won't change the access levels.

Comment: Does not look like a programming question. Try superuser.

Comment: True, not a programming question. chmod was run as root, but did not seem to solve it. I was hoping someone in here is aware of NTFS specific permissions settings that may solve this behavior while mounting on osx 10.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by setting up an NFS server on the windows box with permissions configured and auto-mountable. Works reliably.